# CURL ilink32 Error: Unresolved external

Tags: c++, libcurl, c++builder

My code:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
...
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/");

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        const char *error = curl_easy_strerror(res);
        wchar_t *errorw;
        mbtowc(errorw, error, sizeof(error));
        MessageBox(Application->Handle, L"Test", errorw, 0);
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
curl_global_cleanup();
...
```

When I'm trying to compile my program with libcurl, I'm getting this errors:

```
[ilink32 Error] 
Error: Unresolved external 'WSAIoctl' referenced from ..\LIBCURL.LIB|easy  
... '_Curl_resolver_init' referenced from ..\LIBCURL.LIB|url  
... '_Curl_resolver_cleanup' referenced from ..\LIBCURL.LIB|url  
... '_Curl_set_dns_servers' referenced from ..\LIBCURL.LIB|url  
... '_Curl_resolver_wait_resolv' referenced from ..\LIBCURL.LIB|connect  
... '_Curl_resolver_cancel' referenced from ..\LIBCURL.LIB|url  
... '_Curl_resolver_getaddrinfo' referenced from ..\LIBCURL.LIB|hostasyn  
... '_Curl_resolver_is_resolved' referenced from ..\LIBCURL.LIB|hostip  
... '_Curl_resolver_getsock' referenced from ..\LIBCURL.LIB|multi  
... '_Curl_resolver_global_init' referenced from ..\LIBCURL.LIB|easy  
... '_Curl_resolver_global_cleanup' referenced from ..\LIBCURL.LIB|easy  
... '_Curl_resolver_duphandle' referenced from ..\LIBCURL.LIB|easy
```

**include/curl** copied to **C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\11.0\include**
**lib/libcurl.lib** and **libcurl_imp** added to project via **Project->Add...**

How to fix this error?

**EDIT:**
When I'm compiling just with `libcurl_imp.lib`, all is fine, but programm needs `libcurl.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have copied the library into your build environment you need to explicitly tell it to link the library to your application.

The [embarcadero](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com) website has a nice page on [how to configure your project](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Linking_C%2B%2B_Library_and_Object_Fi) settings to link additional ilbraries.

For the new error you get after using the above solution you need to make some additional changes. First you will need to link the Winsock library called `Ws2_32.lib` in order to use `WSAIoctl`. It's a Windows library so it *should* already be installed in your development environment.

Once you've added that library you will need to double check the libcurl configuration to make sure the proper calls are compiled into the library. You will need to rebuild the library (or download a precompiled version) in order to get these missing function calls. When you build the library that at least `USE_ARES` and `CURLRES_ASYNCH` have been added to the predefined symbols settings of the preprocessor. You will also want to make sure the following additional symbols are defined.

Comment: updated my answer. As a side note it's generally preferred that you make an addendum to your original post if new but _very_ related problems occur after applying a solution. This way any answers that have been provided don't end up looking out of place.

Comment: Maybe you can do step by step instruction, how to normally compile libcurl for C++ Builder XE4?

Comment: If you want to build libcurl for Borland you should read [this webpage](http://www.corona-soft.com/2011/11/compiling-libcurl-with-embarcadero-c.html). You will also need libssl, zlib and possibly other dependencies. My recommendation is that you use one of the generic precompiled libraries available on the [libcurl download page](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html).

Comment: I have compiled my lib with that instruction. Which one of precompiled I should download for last C++ builder?

Comment: Download the generic libraries for either 32bit or 64bit.